# ginput loop for my analysis

Tags: matlab, loops, ginput

So im trying to make a loop for my ginput in matlab, i have the following code:

```
    jpgFiles = dir('*.jpg');
numFiles = length(jpgFiles);
mydata = cell(1,numFiles);

% mydata = zeros(numFiles);
for k = 1:numFiles
    mydata{1,k} = imread(jpgFiles(k).name);
end
for k = 1:numFiles
%     subplot(4,5,k);
    figure;
    imshow(mydata{k});
    [x, y] = ginput(30)
end
```

and i would like to get [x, y] into a matrix 30x6 (30 points and 6 images) 
i have tryed making a for-loop and a function like xx=x(k) but i make it work. Can someone help me do that since it would save me a lot of time for my analysis. 
Im a newbie to matlab so hope you guys can help me since i can't seem to find a useable answer on matworks.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mikkel - rather than a 30x6 matrix of points, perhaps visualize it as a 30x2x6 three-dimensional matrix.  Remember, that your **x** and **y** are 30x1 column arrays and so "putting" them together would give us a 30x2 matrix.  And then for your six images, this would 30x2x6.  Try the following

```
% initialize your array of coordinates
coords = zeros(30,2,numFiles);

for k=1:numFiles
    figure;
    imshow(mydata{k});
    [x, y] = ginput(30)
    coords(:,:,k) = [x y];
end
```

Try the above and see what happens!

Comment: Is it possible to export the variable coords to excel? when i try to use xlswrite i get the following error: Dimension of input array cannot be higher than two. I only need the Y value exported if that makes it easier

Comment: Rather than just exporting the y coordinate, consider using [reshape](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) to reshape the 30x2x6 array into a 30x12 array.